# Why does else behave differently in for/while statements as opposed to if/try statements?

Tags: python, control-flow

I have recently stumbled over a seeming inconsistency in Python's way of dealing with else clauses in different compound statements. Since Python is so well designed, I'm sure that there is a good explanation, but I can't think of it.

Consider the following:

```
if condition:
   do_something()
else:
   do_something_else()
```

Here, `do_something_else()` is only executed if `condition` is false, as expected.

Similarly, in

```
try:
   do_something()
except someException:
   pass:
else:
   do_something_else()
finally:
   cleanup()
```

`do_something_else()` is only executed if no exception occurred.

But in for or while loops, an else clause is always executed, whether the contents of the `for/while block` have been executed or not.

```
for i in some_iterator:
   print(i)
else:
   print("Iterator is empty!")
```

will always print "Iterator is empty!", whether I say `some_iterator = []` or `some_iterator = [1,2,3]`. Same behavior in `while-else` clauses. It seems to me that `else` behaves more like `finally` in these cases. What am I overlooking?

Comment: I'm surprised Python allows the syntax. In most other languages -else is restricted to only being used with if- or switch-statements. For-loops and try-statements might control flow, but they are not conditional like an if-statement, so -else has no place in them.

Comment: For what it's worth, there has been a recent lengthy discussion of for/else, et al, on the python-ideas list, summarized here: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/6131/ .  Guido himself admits to having second thoughts about it: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/6133/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it depends how you see it. You can look at the elses like this (excuse the screaming, its the only way to make emphasis in code):

```
if condition:
   do_something()
IF THE PREVIOUS CONDITION WAS FALSE:
   do_something_else()
```

Now, there is an obvious similarity between if/else and try/except/else, if you see the else statement as an else to the except statement. Like this.

```
try:
   do_something()
IF THERE WAS AN EXCEPTION:
   pass:
IF THE PREVIOUS CONDITION WAS FALSE:
   do_something_else()
finally:
   cleanup()
```

Same goes for the else/for:

```
IF some_iterator IS NOT EMPTY:
   i = next(some_iterator)
   print(i)
IF THE PREVIOUS CONDITION WAS FALSE:
   print("Iterator is empty!")
```

So here we see that the else in some fundamental way *do* work exactly the same in all three cases.

But you can also see the else in this way:

```
try:
   do_something()
except someException:
   pass:
IF NO EXCEPTION:
   do_something_else()
finally:
   cleanup()
```

And then it's not the same anymore, but the else because a sort of "if nothing else". You can see for/else in the same way:

```
for i in some_iterator:
   print(i)
IF NO MORE ITERATING:
   print("Iterator is empty!")
```

But then again, considering the elif, then this way of seeing it works for if/else as well:

```
if condition:
   do_something()
elif otherconditaion:
   do_anotherthing()
IF NO CONDITION WAS TRUE:
   do_something_else()
```

Which way you want to look at the else is up to you, but in both ways of viewing, else do have similarities in all three cases.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and answers my question.

Answer (score 13):

The `for else` construct executes the `else` clause if no `break` statement was executed for the loop, [as described here](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)  For example, this else clause is never evaluated

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i % 5 == 0:
       print i
       break
else:
    print "nothing divisible by 5"
```

Comment: Right, so a for/while-else statement only makes sense if there is a break statement somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Eli mentioned, the else clause is executed only if you don't break.  It stops you from implementing code like this:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    if i % 5 == 0:
       print i
       break
if i % 5 != 0:
   print "nothing divisible by 5"
```

Which is roughly equivalent here, but handy if the conditions for quitting are a bit more complicated (like checking various possible conditions or combinations of conditions).