# Why does this indentation work? python

Tags: python, indentation

here is my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False

    else:
        for i in range(2,x):
            if x % i == 0:
                return False
        else:
            return True

print is_prime(508)
```

I don't understand why the last `else: return true` works with the indentation. If I type

```
else:
            for i in range(2,x):
                if x % i == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
```

Then def is_prime(2) returns none? why?

Comment: There is nice blog on this topic "Reasons for Confusion": https://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html. I would recommend using other constructs as it is really confusing you and future reader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because in python, a `for`-loop can have an `else`-clause.

This clause is executed if the loop exits normally. If the loop is exited by using the `break` statement, the `else` is not entered.

I suggest you read up the official [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and if it's still unclear, [this blog](http://psung.blogspot.fi/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html) summarizes the concept fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

`for` and `while` loops also know `else` clauses, not just `if` or `try` statements.

The `else` clause of a loop is executed when control leaves the loop, unless you have used `break` to abort the loop.

I must admit that this behavior [puzzled me at first, as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576537/why-does-else-behave-differently-in-for-while-statements-as-opposed-to-if-try-st), but it's actually quite sensible, and a useful feature (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576552/20670) for a good example).

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, the `else` is on the same indentation level as the `if`, so they both belong together. So for the first item in the loop, you will either return `False` or `True` depending on that value; i.e. the loop won’t continue.

Now in your original code, the `else` is on the same level as the `for`. So it’s a `for..else` which is actually [a special construct](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> When the items are exhausted, the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.

So basically, the else block is executed, if the loop naturally finishes (without calling `break`). So in your case, it’s the same as leaving the `else` out:

```
for i in range(2,x):
    if x % i == 0:
        return False
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a for loop can have an else clause. Read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

> When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with 
>   the else clause of a try statement than it does that of if statements: 
>   a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a 
>   loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs.